# Accessing GUI element is not working as intended

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, user-interface, task

When I run the below code it is supposed fill the `ListBox` with each `DataRow`'s values, but it is filling the `ListBox` with single `DataRow`'s value.

What is the problem and how can I solve it? This is a C# 4.0 WPF application.

```
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        myThread();
    });

void myThread()
{
    using (DataTable dtTemp = DbConnection.db_Select_DataTable(srQuery))
    {
        foreach (DataRow drw in dtTemp.Rows)
        {   
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate()
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(drw["Value"].ToString());
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you're capturing the `drw` variable in your anonymous method. That variable is being updated in the `foreach` loop, so by the time your delegates are invoked on the dispatcher thread, you're getting the same value each time. In C# 5, this would be okay (it's such a common error that the language has changed to avoid it) but before C# 5 you need to copy the variable in the loop:

```
foreach (DataRow drw in dtTemp.Rows)
{   
    DataRow copy = drw;
    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate()
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(copy["Value"].ToString());
    }));
}
```

Or even better, do all the data access in the background thread:

```
foreach (DataRow drw in dtTemp.Rows)
{   
    string item = drw["Value"].ToString();
    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate()
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(item);
    }));
}
```

Note that the change to C# 5 *only* affects `foreach` - not `for` loops.

Also note that your code can be slightly shorted using a lambda expression instead of an anonymous method:

```
foreach (DataRow drw in dtTemp.Rows)
{   
    string item = drw["Value"].ToString();
    Action action = () => listBox1.Items.Add(item);
    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action);
}
```

Comment: nice i started loving C# 5 from now :D

Comment: Also do you prefer this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke or  Task.Factory.StartNew with uiScheduler

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG: In C# 5 I'd probably use an async method to start with if possible. But failing that, probably `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` - but not for any particular reason.

Answer (score 4):

Variable capturing strikes again. (Google: [variable capture](http://google.com/search?q=variable+capture))

Try creating a temporary variable and passing that to the thread, like this:

```
void myThread()
{
    using (DataTable dtTemp = DbConnection.db_Select_DataTable(srQuery))
    {
        foreach (DataRow drw in dtTemp.Rows)
        {
            DataRow tmp = drw;
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate()
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(tmp["Value"].ToString());
            }));
        }
    }
}
```